# Deploying Ruby on Rails 2.3 on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Am sorry for the noobness for this,

I am developing a ruby on rails application on my ubuntu 14.04.
As for development, i'm starting my application using `ruby script/server`.
Ruby -v 1.8.7
Rails -v 2.3.14
MySql

Now my question is how to deploy this on production?
Am planning to use Ubuntu 14.04 Server as well.

I read about the Phusion Passenger but I did not understand what is that for.

I was hoping to make the ubuntu server as a localhost. So that if I point to the browser like `myrailsapp`, my application will be available (Normally I will use `script/server`). Do I have to use the `script/server` command everytime the server will restart?

Please tell me if im on the right track.

------------ I follow a tutorial --------------

I follow a tutorial like this one but I can't figure out how to make a virtual host working I created a virtual host like this: 
/etc/hosts 
`0.0.0.0 example.com`

/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    passenger_enabled on;

    location / {
        root   /opt/nginx/html/ror/blog/public;
    }
}
```

On my browser i get 403 Forbidden And do i have to start my rails app like script/server?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

http://www.codesapling.com/blog/2014/04/12/set-up-guide-for-rails-server-on-ubuntu/

or

http://codebeerstartups.com/2012/10/complete-guide-to-setup-a-rails-server/

PS : May be the links outdated but help you getting started.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need to run script/server every time.
set-up your Rails-App in the server, install rails version with the command

```
sudo gem install rails ­-v 2.3.1
```

now install Passenger and Nginx Web Server

```
sudo apt-­get install libssl0.9.8

sudo passenger-­install-­nginx­-module
```

follow the onscreen instructions, it would show you the ways to install missing packages.
After the missing packages are installed, run the above command again.
Enter choice 1
Press enter when asked for default path (/opt/nginx)

After completion nginx 
Configuring Web Server at

```
 cd /opt/nginx/conf/
```

Comment: Yes, I follow a tutorial like this one but I can't figure out how to make a virtual host working

I created a virtual host like this:
/etc/hosts
`0.0.0.0         example.com`

/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
`  server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;
        passenger_enabled on;

        location / {
            root   /opt/nginx/html/ror/blog/public;
        }
    }
`

On my browser i get 403 Forbidden
And do i have to start my rails app like script/server?